# the difference between a subshell and detach in bash or zsh?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh

what would be for instance be the diffence between doing:

```
(ls | sort) ; ls
```

and

```
{ls | sort} & ; ls
```

since when doing this in a shell like bash or zsh there is no difference.
thnx for the reply beforehand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second case, the final `ls` is executed immediately. In the first case, it is executed after the subshell (and hence the `sort` command) terminates.